# How to manage multithread c# application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have following scenario:

C# application (.net 4.0/4.5), with 5-6 different threads. Every thread has a different task, which is launched every x seconds (ranging from 5 to 300).

Each task has following steps:

1. Fetch items from Sql Server
2. Convert items in Json
3. Send data to webserver
4. Wait for reply from server.

Since this tasks can fail at some point (internet problems, timeout, etc) what is best solution in .NET world?

I thought about following solutions:

- Spawn new thread every x seconds (if there is not another thread of this type in execution)
- Spawn one thread for each type of task and loop steps every x seconds (to understand the way to manage exceptions)

Which would be more secure and robust? Application will run on unattended systems, so it should be able to remain in execution regardless of any possible exception.

Comment: My first question would be to really determine if multi-threading is actually necessary, as it does add a significant barrier to entry, and maintainability problem. The percieved performance boost is almost never there. If you are multi-threading to provide a responsive UI, you should consider async/await first, which reduces complexity.

Comment: I think [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) is the right tool for this. There are some nice examples of its use here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threads are pretty expensive to create. The first option isn't a great one. If the cycle of "do stuff" is pretty brief (between the pauses), you might consider using the `ThreadPool` or the TPL. If the threads are mostly busy, or the work takes any appreciable time, then dedicated workers are more appropriate.

As for exceptions: don't let exceptions escape workers. You *must* catch them. If all that means is that you give up and retry in a few seconds, that is probably fine.

Comment: Can you expand on the implications of not catching exceptions on workers?

Comment: I hate to tell you but "a thread every couple of seconds" - threads are not THAT Expensive that it makes a difference. Not at all.

Comment: @TomTom the stack alone is a MB ;p But my point is that there are often *more appropriate* ways to process work, depending on the profile of the work involved

Comment: @MarcGravell I never said they are cheap, but if you have to spawn a thread every 5 seconds to check something then the "expensive" is a joke. 1mb is not relevant for what most applicaitons do.

Comment: about catching exception on workers: generic try {} catch (Exception ex) catches all possible exceptions in c# right?

Comment: @TomTom but it is also most likely unnecessary - both in terms of (questionable, in your view) overhead **and** (more importantly) complexity. If you keep it simple, you don't always need to worry about things like `Thread`.

Comment: @Alekc not *quite*... there are some exceptions that can't be caught, or which will be rethrown even if you catch them - but: those are severe critical failures, and your app is already doomed at that point. It would be extremely rare that you'd need to worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could have modeled the whole thing using a producer consumer pattern approach. You have a producer who puts the new task description in the queue and you can have multiple consumers (4 or 5 threads) who process from the queue. The number of consumers or the processing thread could vary depending on the load, length of the queue.

Each task involves reading from DB, converting the format, sending to web server and then process the response from web server. I assume each task would do all these steps.

In case of exceptions for an item in the queue, you could potentially mark the queue item as failed and schedule it for a retry later.